# Splitting string on command line argument

Tags: c#

I have a program that extracts data from files, it is ran on a 3rd party scheduler that scans a folder for file. The issue im having is it is reading all files in a folder and reading it as if it is one big file Example:

File1.txt
File2.txt

But treating it like the file name is File1.txtFile2.txt

I decided to try and split the string in the command line argument and use that.

I know it has something to do with string splitting and then a foreach loop but for the life of me, i cant get it to work

here is my original code before trying the split

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = "";
        string output = "";

        try
        {
            if (args.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (string s in args)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
                }
                input = args[0];
                output = args[1];
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Input");
                input = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Output Location");
                output = Console.ReadLine();
            }
```

How can i sort this?

Comment: pls tell us what doesnt work and what you want to achieve? Program arguments should be seperated by a space. This *File1.txtFile2.txt* will be interpreted as one argument

Comment: @lokusking Read the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work BUT it is making the assumption that all the files are txt files with .txt as their extension AND that you only have one argument (All of your files are combined into one string, so args would only read one argument).

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string input = args[0];
    List<string> files = input.Split('.').ToList<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < files.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        files[i] = files[i].Replace("txt","");
        files[i] += ".txt";
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < files.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(files[i]);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Yes all the files will be the same format, not sure what yet but ive been playing with text files . Thats the idea i was thinking of, putting it into one string. I will be giving this a try asap. Thank you for reply

Comment: No problem, hope all goes well.